# Double factorial formula

Tags: factorial

I don't know why this is true:

$$(2k+1)!!=\frac{(2k+1)!}{2^kk!}$$

Can anyone explain it for me? I know what is double factorial, but would like to know how this formula was derived. Thanks.

Comment: If $x!! = (x!)!$, then this is certainly not true, since $(2k+1)!! > (2k+1)!>\frac{(2k+1)!}{2^{k}k!}$.

Comment: @HerbertQuain: The double-bang symbol does not stand for the iterated factorial, it means: $$a!!=a(a-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(a-2\lfloor (a-1)/2\rfloor).$$

Comment: @HerbertQuain. Hummmm $(2k+1)!! > (2k+1)!$ does not seem correct to me

Comment: Okay, my bad. The author might define this symbol in his post, then.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I learned something again. Btw, couldn't they think of something better? Very confusing.

Comment: @HerbertQuain. The title says "double factorial" ! I have this kind of problems too ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Well, I didn't knew "double factorial" meant something different than factorial of the factorial. I apologize :)

Comment: @HerbertQuain apologize? I think that the inventors of this notation owe you an apology.

Comment: Might be worth noting the (n-1)!! is the number of ways 2n objects can be paired off into n different pairs. Thought it might be good to include an application.

Answer (score 3):

HINT :
$$(2k+1)!!=1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \cdots (2k-1)\cdot (2k+1)$$
$$(2k+1)!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \cdots (2k)\cdot (2k+1) $$
$$2^k\cdot k!=2^k\times \{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \cdots (k-1)\cdot k\}=2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot\cdots (2k-2)\cdot (2k).$$

Answer (score 2):

By multiplying both sides by $(2k)!! = (2k)(2k-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot 2 = 2^k\cdot k!$, you get: $$(2k+1)! = (2k+1)!.$$